# Send HTTP headers before or after a cookie header?

Tags: php, cookies, http-headers

I was wondering if there are any problems or difference between sending normal headers before or after sending cookie headers. Do some browsers prefer a certain order to headers? If the cookie header is to large would subsequent headers never be parsed?

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
```

or

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
setcookie("TestCookie", $value);
```

or

```
setcookie("SuperLargeCookie", $massive_value);
setcookie("TinyCookie", $small_value);
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference. The Http protocol does not specify that headers are to be in a certain order. Browsers do not differentiate based on the order of headers either.

The total length of Http headers does have a limit. This limit is imposed by the server and not the browser. Typically between 8K and 16K. However this is configurable.

Answer (score 2):

It really doesn't matter as long as the other HTTP headers have not been sent. `setcookie()` actually writes a header itself:

```
Set-Cookie: SuperLargeCookie=whatever; Max-Age=3600; Version=1
```

similar to a `header()` call:

```
Location: http://www.example.com/redirect
```

Comment: "It really doesn't matter as long as the other HTTP headers have not been sent" ...wait, so then it does matter?

Comment: if you have intervening text output between headers and setcookie, it will matter. and you'll get the familiar "headers already sent" error

Answer (score 1):

HTTP messages span packets all the time, so you'd be hard-pressed to overfill one unless you're jamming tons of kilobytes in there.  If you need to do that, consider a better design.  Browsers don't care about the order of headers since different servers (and applications) append headers all the time.  Cookies are implemented as HTTP headers, so they should appear like so in the HTTP request:

```
Cookie: TestCookie=value\r\n
Content-type: text/javascript\r\n
\r\n
```

I'm not sure what the Status header is supposed to do in your example, but I don't think it's right since the webserver will set a 200 OK response code if the code executes correctly... The **header** function page has this examaple:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
?>
```

With the PHP **header** function, just make sure you're not writing any text out before issuing it.  Otherwise, you could mess everything up.

Comment: The status header is for PHPFastcgi - and was just an example.